# Laravel 5.2 : How to write the controller of this questionnaire demo?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 ， 
How to write the controller of this questionnaire demo below:

There are 3 tables,
`respondents`,`sports`, they have a "many-to-many" relationship,another one is `sport_respondent`,which is the relational table of  the former two.

**respondents**

```
id   name   email
```

**sports**

```
id   sport_name
1    Basketball
2    Football
3    Table tennis
4    Badminton
5    Baseball
6    Swimming
```

**sport_respondent**

```
id   respondent_id   sport_id
```

view：

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
        </fieldset>
        <div class="checkbox row">
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport1" name="sport[]" value="1">Basketball
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport2" name="sport[]" value="2">Football
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport3" name="sport[]" value="3">Table tennis
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport4" name="sport[]" value="4">Badminton
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport5" name="sport[]" value="5">Baseball
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="sport6" name="sport[]" value="6">Swimming
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question：**How to write the controller below？

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $respondent= new Respondent;
    $respondent->name = $request->name;
    $respondent->email = $request->email;
    $respondent->save();

    $sport = new Sport;
    //how to write here？
    return redirect()->action('RespondentController@index');
}
```

**edit:**

this is the new `store` method according to @AlexeyMezenin ,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $respondent= new Respondent;
    $respondent->name = $request->name;
    $respondent->email = $request->email;

    $respondent->sports()->attach($request->sports);

    $respondent->save();

    return redirect()->action('RespondentController@index');
}
```

there is an infomation when running it,

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'respondent_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sport_respondent` (`respondent_id`, `sport_id`) values (, 1))
```

it shows that `respondent_id` is needed,I don't know how to add it,some help please.

Comment: You must have saved the model using `$respondent->save()` before attaching anything to it not after it. The attach method automatically pushes the relationship to the intermediate table so no need to call save after it.

Comment: @DavidBarker , it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) method:

```
$respondent->sports()->attach($request->sports);
```

If you have setup relations correctly and `$request->sports` contains an array of sport IDs, this will work.

Comment: there is no  `respondent_id`,  I don't know how to add it:    ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'respondent_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sport_respondent` (`respondent_id`, `sport_id`) values (, 1))``` .